# Rstudio: Combining row values into one row based on duplicate values in column

Tags: r

[image]

I screenshotted part of my table that I'm using in Rstudio.  I want to combine the rows that have the same middle column value like "01020" and combine the 3rd columns' values together into one so the 01020 row would be 2 instead of 1.  I don't care about retaining the 1st column.  How would I do this?

Comment: You may use `aggregate(col3 ~ col2, df1, FUN = sum)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `aggeregate`

```
aggregate(col3 ~ col2, df1, FUN = sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `(reshape2)`

```
df2 <- dcast(df1, col1 ~ col2, value.var = "col3", fun.aggregate = sum)
```